# Linear Transformation from R3 to R2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb  R^2$

$f((1,2,3)) = (2,1)$ and $f((2,3,4)) = (2,4)$

How can I write the associated matrix?

I tried to write the matrix with the standard base:

$$(2,1) = v_1$$
$$(2,4) = v_2$$

$v_1 = af(1,0,0) + bf(0,1,0) + cf(0,0,1)$
Same for $v_2$

1 2 3 v1

2 3 4 v2

I tried to solve this matrix and I get a free variable (x3 = f(0,0,1)).
So I dont know how to go on from here.

Comment: What have you tried ? Please **EDIT** your post to show your work.

Comment: Edited. Is it ok now?

Comment: That's better. To make your post more readable you can **EDIT** your post to put \$ symbols around the mathematical expressions. For example writing \$V_1 = af(0,0,1)\$ will write $V_1 = af(0,0,1)$ which is far easier to read.

Comment: How you can get a free variable?

Comment: @Tim i edited the post with the matrix

Comment: @Digitallis how can i write a matrix?

Comment: [mathjax tuto](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You can see an example here $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & z & z^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You will need $6$ coefficients $a,b,c$ on row 1 and $d,e,f$ on row 2 but have only $4$ equations. So simplify your life and set $c=0,f=0$ i.e $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&0\end{pmatrix}$ The resulting system to solve is not complicated.

Comment: @zwim and how can i write the associated matrix from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually use the action of the map on the basis elements of the domain to get the matrix representing the linear map. In this problem, we must solve two systems of equations where each system has more unknowns than constraints.

Let $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}$$ be the matrix representing the linear map. We know it has this shape because we are mapping a three dimensional space to a two dimensional space.

Our first system of equations is $$a+2b+3c=2\\2a+3b+4c=2$$ This gives the augmented matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&3&2\\2&3&4&2\end{array}\right]$$ which we can solve to give $$a=-2, b=2, c=0$$

Note that since we have more unknowns that equations we choose $c=0$. Other choices may work as well.

Likewise, to get the second row of the matrix we solve $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&2&3&1\\2&3&4&4\end{array}\right]$$ to get $$d=5,e=-2, f=0$$ so our final matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}-2&2&0\\5&-2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Notice that we were given four equations and six unknowns so we were free to set two of the unknowns, in this case $c$ and $f$, to zero. Other choices could have been made so this solution is not unique.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do the same thing in a different way.
Let v1 = (2,1) and v2 = (2,4)
v1 = f(1,0,0) + 2*f(0,1,0)+3*f(0,0,1)
v2 = 2*f(1,0,0) + 3*f(0,1,0) + 4*f(0,0,1)

The matrix is:

1 2 3 | v1
2 3 4 | v2

At the end i get:
f(1,0,0) = (-2,-7)
f(0,1,0) =(2,-2)

So my final matrix is:
-2 2 0
-7 -2 0

Do you know where is the error?

Comment: @userbob For future reference, here is a [Mathjax tutorial.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Using Mathjax makes your formulas easier to read. Also, after reading the comments under your post, I suspect you received downvotes because you didn't orginally post your attempt. That makes all the difference in the world on this site. What you said about your attempt seems reasonable and would have been better received if it had been formatted better. Please don't get discouraged and welcome to the site.